# Delete item from an updated list

Tags: entity-framework

I have this situation here. 2 classes

```
    public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Phone> Phones { get; set; }

}

public class Phone
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

Person is already stored in database with some phones. So, let's say I'll edit it's phones.
The current list of phone is:

> Id: 1 Number: 1111
>
> Id: 2 Number: 2222
>
> Id: 3 Number: 3333

And when i edited the list, I removed the second line and updated the first one. Now, the list is:

> Id: 1 Number: 1212
>
> Id: 3 Number: 3333

-

The command below will update the Person and the edited phones:

```
context.Person.Update(person)
```

But what about the deleted phone? I'll have to compare the current and edited list to determine which phones were deleted to do something like

```
context.Phone.Delete(phone)
```

My question is: Isn't there anything more automatic? Can't Entity detect which phones were deleted?

Tks!

Comment: as far my knowledge goes, entities are not intelligent enough to figure out if its related values or data are missing...unlike database system. there must be some constraints, rules etc. so that you can define such situations in your program.

Comment: Why update the person when there are no changes to the actual person? Wouldn't deleting the phone be enough ?

Answer (score 0):

The same `Phone` entity might belong to multiple Persons. EF does not necessarily know this since in most cases not all the `Person` entities will downloaded from the database. So, blindly deleting the `Phone` entity could affect relationships/entities that should not be touched. If you want to delete a related entity and update the relationship in a single stop you could try just `Delete` on the `Phone` entity and I think you will not have to have to call `Update` on the other entity.

Comment: Ok, but the question is other.

Comment: Removing an entity from the collection of related entities does not mean that the entity should be removed from the database but that the relationship between the two entities no longer exists. Deleting the related entity means that the entity should be deleted and that the relationship should be removed. Since you are talking about the first case EF cannot and won't delete the entity only because you removed the relationship